# Send a command/argument to a command prompt that's already opened

Tags: c#, windows, command-line-arguments, command-prompt

So I know that I can already fire up a `cmd.exe` process and enter `ping google.com` into it the moment it opens up. This can be accomplished easily like so:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SendComandToCMD
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
            processStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

            Process process = Process.Start(processStartInfo);

            if (process != null)
            {            
                process.StandardInput.WriteLine("ping google.com");

                process.StandardInput.Close(); // line added to stop process from hanging on ReadToEnd()

                lblResult.Text = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd(); // return CMD.exe output to the Form label here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And boom, such easy.

However, the example below theoretically does what I want it to do but it crashes:

```
namespace SendComandToCMD
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Process process = Process.GetProcessById(22180); // Grab a process which is already running by its ID

            if (process != null)
            {            
                process.StandardInput.WriteLine("ping google.com");

                process.StandardInput.Close(); // line added to stop process from hanging on ReadToEnd()

                lblResult.Text = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd(); // return CMD.exe output to the Form label here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So grabbing the instance of the newly created process like the very first example works perfectly, however grabbing an instance of a currently running CMD.EXE process by the ID will result in a crash:

`An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.dll`

I know for a fact that by checking task manager that I have a cmd.exe running with a PID of 22180, however the exception occurs on:

`process.StandardInput.WriteLine("ping google.com");`

It is extremely important that I find a way to write to CMD.EXEs for a multitude of reasons, does anyone know how I could get solution 2 above to work?

Comment: What's the full exception? Use `ex.ToString()` to get the whole thing.

Comment: Seems to be: `System.InvalidOperationException: StandardIn has not been redirected.
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.get_StandardInput()
   at SendComandToCMD.Form1.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\Matt\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\SendComandToCMD\SendComandToCMD\Form1.cs:line 30`

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardinput%28v=vs.110%29.aspx. It says you need to set a property first.